# How to send Window Events using NXLOG to RSYSLOG server

Tags: window, rsyslog, nxlog, eventlog-source, p-lang

I am trying to send window logs to rsyslog server which is deployed on Azure Cloud. I have configured on both "nxlog" and "rsyslog". But the nxlog does not send any log to the server. I have allowed 514 port for outbound traffic in Window Firewall. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Please provide the configuration of both `nxlog` and `rsyslog`. Without seeing the actual configuration, it's impossible to know where the issue lies. Additionally, please check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.